# MDX: Query if row exists in dimension

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, ssrs-2012

I have created a SSAS Tabular model cube which this connects too.
The cube contains
Measures: - CountA, SumB, CountC, SumD, CountE
Dimensions: 
 - TblLabelDefinition(ID,Definition,Type)
 - TblLabels(ID,Type,reference,date,sold,leftover,A,B,C,D,E)
 - References(ID,reference,date)

Below is a query I am working on:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
    { 
     [Measures].[CountA], 
     [Measures].[SumB], 
     [Measures].[CountC], 
     [Measures].[SumD], 
     [Measures].[CountE] 
    } 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
    { 
     (
      [TblLabelDefinition].[Definition].[Definition].ALLMEMBERS * 
      [TblLabels].[Type].[Type].ALLMEMBERS 
     ) 
    }
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT ( -{ [TblLabels].[sold].&[1] } ) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM 
            ( SELECT ( { [TblLabels].[leftover].&[0] } ) ON COLUMNS 
                FROM [Model]
            )
    ) 
WHERE 
        ( [TblLabels].[leftover].&[0] ) 
        AND 
        (
         EXISTS([TblLabels].[reference], [References].[reference])
        )   
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, 
FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

I am trying to check if reference in the TblLabels table exists in References table.

This is the error I get:
The And function expects a string or numeric expression for the 2 argument. A tuple set expression was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below to get rid of the syntactic error:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
    { 
     [Measures].[CountA], 
     [Measures].[SumB], 
     [Measures].[CountC], 
     [Measures].[SumD], 
     [Measures].[CountE] 
    } 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
    { 
     (
      [TblLabelDefinition].[Definition].[Definition].ALLMEMBERS * 
      [TblLabels].[Type].[Type].ALLMEMBERS 
     ) 
    }
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT ( -{ [TblLabels].[sold].&[1] } ) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM 
            ( SELECT ( { [TblLabels].[leftover].&[0] } ) ON COLUMNS 
                FROM [Model]
            )
    ) 
WHERE 
        (
         [TblLabels].[leftover].&[0]
         , 
        (
         EXISTS
              (
               [TblLabels].[reference], 
               [References].[reference]
              )
        ))   
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, 
FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

As a side note:

```
     EXISTS
          (
           [TblLabels].[reference], 
           [References].[reference]
          )
```

yields a set of those references that exists in the table `TblLabels` for one or more references in the table `References`. If these tables are joined on the 'reference' column then the above `EXISTS` construct would return only those references that are present in both `References` and `TblLabels`. Do check if that is what you needed in the first place.

Comment: Thank you!!! Awesome SouravA. It works now. I copied over the Exists statement and its working.